# Get two 2 randomly selected words from 2 separate lists

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am trying to put a little js on a webpage to randomly select a word from one list and another word from another list when you click on the random button. At the moment I am using the following code to get a single word returned from one list but I can not work out how to make it work with multiple lists of words.

```
    <body>
<a id="myButton" href="#">
Random
</a>
<div id="myRandomDiv">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
var randomStrings = [
    "Jack",
    "Jill",
    "Michael", 
    "Roger",
    "Thomas",
    "Samuel",
    "stranger",
];

var randomDiv = document.getElementById("myRandomDiv");

document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
      randomIndex = Math.ceil((Math.random()*randomStrings.length-1));
      newText = randomStrings[randomIndex];
      randomDiv.innerHTML = newText;
});
</script>  
</body>
```

Thanks for the help
-Samuel

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
var randomStrings1 = ["a", "b", "c"];
var randomStrings2 = ["d", "e", "f"];
var randomDiv = document.getElementById("myRandomDiv");

document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
   randomIndex1 = Math.ceil((Math.random()*randomStrings1.length-1));
   randomIndex2 = Math.ceil((Math.random()*randomStrings2.length-1));
   newText = randomStrings1[randomIndex1] + randomStrings2[randomIndex2];
   randomDiv.innerHTML = newText;
});
</script>
```

This will select a random string from 2 different lists (randomStrings1 and randomStrings2), and concatenate them.

Comment: Thank you very much, I feel very simple now haha.